# Windows File Explorer large text

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-explorer

[image]

I'm not sure when this started so I can't tell if it's something I have edited but the text in Window's file explorer is bigger than usual. It is also large on the menu when you right click an icon on the taskbar.

I am using Windows 8.1, with Classic Shell and I have patched my system for custom themes. However, the text was normal sized after installing these things at the start.

Is there a setting I have overlooked in correcting this? Thanks.

Comment: ware you able fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To increase or decrease the size of text and icons**

**1.** *Right-click anywhere on the desktop, then click Screen resolution.*

**2.** *Click Make text and other items larger or smaller.*

**3.** *Choose one of the following:*

```
   *Smaller - 100%. This keeps text and other items at normal size.*

   *Medium - 125%. This sets text and other items to 125 percent of normal size.*

   *Larger - 150%. This sets text and other items to 150 percent of normal size. (Require monitor resolution of at least 1200 × 900 pixels.)
```

**4.** *Click Apply.*

To see the change, close all of your programs, log off of Windows, and then log on again.

**To set ClearType**

ClearType font technology makes the text on your screen appear almost as sharp and clear.

**1.** *Open the ClearType Text Tuner by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start button, and then clicking Control Panel. In the search box, type cleartype, and then click Adjust ClearType text.*

**2.** *first page of the tuner, select the check box next to Turn on ClearType, and then click Next.*

**3.** *Follow the steps on each page, and then click Finish to turn on ClearType and save your settings.*

**Administrator permission required.**

[image]

[image]

Next

Comment: This wasn't the exact solution, but the solution was in the same settings window. In Windows 8.1, there is a few options to change only certain text sizes. Obviously I had messed around with this and hadn't changed an option back. Thanks Omar.

Comment: I'm glad you figured it.